# HTML5 Color Picker - color not changed

Tags: color-picker

I've noticed a strange behavior with the color picker.  When I pick any color from the *basic colors* (predefined colors), the button's color (the one of the html input element) is changed accordingly.

However, when picking any other color from the the gradient color picker, the button's color won't change. It will stay white. (Note: Don't pick a basic color first or refresh the jsbin page first if you're going to test it)

**But**... when I first pick a basic color and press *OK* and then pick a color from the gradient color picker, the button's color will change. 
(Tested with Chrome 69)

Video (gif):
https://giphy.com/gifs/8vCEY7uyz8m17N0bkz

Test it:
http://output.jsbin.com/ivAhORu/1

```
   var i = 0;
    var inp=document.createElement("input"); 
    inp.type = 'color';
    inp.id = 'colo_'+i;
    inp.value = '#ffffff';
    inp.className = 'datafield';
    document.body.appendChild(inp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually an error, when you set a color picker to pure white or pure black the luminosity is adjusted to give you the desired color. When you pick a swatch the luminosity is changed to that swatch so it seems like it wasn't working before, but in fact it was working and if you adjusted the luminosity you'd see the color change correctly. You might want to consider a different starting color other than pure black or pure white.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Makes Sense.